# Auto-rewrite Mixed Content HTTP links in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, https, browser-addons, microsoft-edge

There are a few websites I visit that have mixed content (reference to HTTP resources on HTTPS pages). Because of browser's policy on mixed content, those pages don't function normally. However all HTTP resources also loads properly, so I think I could make those pages work by forcing the browser to "upgrade insecure requests", by internally redirecting the JavaScript and CSS resources to HTTPS scheme.

I have the following extensions installed, but unfortunately browser is still showing errors on blocked insecure resources in F12 Developer Tools:

- HTTPS Everywhere (EFF.org)
- Resource Override (by manually adding rewrite rules)

I can confirm that all extensions are working normally by navigating to the HTTP link, and the browser automatically loads it over HTTPS (or load the overridden resource) instead.

[Here's a page for testing](https://international.download.nvidia.com/geforce-com/international/comparisons/grand-theft-auto-v/grand-theft-auto-v-soft-shadows-interactive-comparison-1-nvidia-pcss-vs-amd-chs.html) if you need. I am on Microsoft Edge 90 (Chromium-based).